# Python docstrings и sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Пытаюсь организовать автоматическую генерацию доки из *docstrings* в исходных файлах Python, используя для этого *sphinx*. Честно говоря - ничего не понимаю! :-(

Если в корне проекта выполнить команду *make html*, то генерируется только *index.html* в котором ни одна ссылка не работает, да и нет никаких других файлов.

Я предположил, что это от того, что в файле *index.rst* НЕ перечислены файлы проекта. Я их там перечилил (Питоновские, без расширений!). Ничего не изменилось

Так как *sphinx* работает с *rst* файлами, то я предполагал, что они будут автоматически генерироваться неким инструментом сфинкса. Ни фига...

Попробовал вручную сгенерировать *rst* по *py* так:

```
sphinx-autogen inquiry.py
```

Ничего не произошло. Т.е. вообще - ничего. Никаких новых файлов, никаких сообщений об ошибках - ничего!

Читая доку про сфинкс, наткнулся на страничку, где описано, "Include documentation from docstrings". (http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) Ага, это же как раз то, что мне нужно!

Но не понял - ничего :-( Какие экстеншены, куда их втыкать, в какие файлы вставлять директивы... ?!

Может мне кто-то в двух словах объяснить, как решить такую задачу:

Есть проект, который состоит из питоновских файлов

```
p1.py
p2.py
....
pN.py
```

1. Внутри этих файлов используются *docstrings*. Какие операторы  разметки можно использовать внутри *docstrings*?
2. Как настроить *sphinx*, *Makefile*, *conf.py* и *index.rst* что бы введя команду *make help* можно было получить результат - готовую доку?

Как просто всё было в Doxygen... :-(

Answer (score 2):

После долгих мытарств я добился того, что *Sphinx* начал генерировать доку непосредственно из кода *Python* программы. Даже написал небольшую инструкцию.  И даже отформатировал её как reStructuredText :-)

Вот только не знаю, как можно выложить её в виде ответа на вопрос...    Отдельного раздела "Статьи" на этом сайте нет, а кнопочки "Прикрепить" в редакторе ответов я не вижу.

Если кому-то нужно до зареза - пишите в личку, отправлю почтой.

---

## Получаем документацию с помощью Sphinx

Создаём каталог проекта и переходим в него:

```
mkdir proj_name
cd proj_name
```

### Генерация конфигурационных файлов

В этом каталоги вызываем скрипт (Должен быть доступ в иНет!):

```
sphinx-quickstart
```

Скрипт задаёт кучу вопросов, на большинство из которых можно ответить нажатие клавиши *Enter*, что означает - можно принять значение по умолчанию. Есть несколько вопросов, ответы по умолчанию на которые не подходят.

```
> Separate source and build directories (y/n) [n]: y
> Project name: Larionov
> Author name(s): Sergey Larionov
> Project release []: 1.0.0
> Project language [en]:ru
> autodoc: automatically insert docstrings from modules (y/n) [n]: y
```

В каталоге проекта будут созданы два подкаталога:

- build
- source

А в корне проекта будет сгенерирован *Makefile*.

В каталоге *source* располагаются сгенерированные файлы:

- conf.py
- index.rst

Их надо отредактировать.

### Правка конфигурационных файлов

В файле *conf.py* раскомментируем строки

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
```

В файле *index.rst*, после строки *:caption: Contents:* перечисляем всё, что мы собрались документировать.  Это перечисление должно иметь вид спсика директив:

```
.. automodule:: <Имя модуля>
   :members:

.. autofunction:: <Имя функции>
   :members:

.. autoclass:: <Имя класса>
   :members:
```

Отсутствие параметров у команды *:members:* означает - включать всё. Для того, что бы *sphinx* мог найти исходные тексты модулей, их надо положить в каталог *source*.

Подробно эти директивы описаны тут: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html

### Как документировать исходы

*Sphinx* сможет обнаружить и вставить элементы для докментирования, если они:

1. Расположены в *docstring* т.е. внутри тройных кавычек;
2. Имеют вид команд *sphinx* с их параметрами. Например, для документирования модуля:

   ```
   """
   .. module:: useful_1
       :platform: Unix, Windows
       :synopsis: A useful module indeed.

   .. moduleauthor:: Andrew Carter <andrew@invalid.com>
   """
   ```

А функция документируется как-то так:

```
"""This function does something.

:param name: The name to use.
:type name: str.
:param state: Current state to be in.
:type state: bool.
:returns:  int -- the return code.
:raises: AttributeError, KeyError

"""
```

Подробно документирование в исходах *python* описано здесь:

[Документирование в Python](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html)

### Генерация доки

В каталоге проекта выполнить команду:

```
make html
```

Этот текст -  резюме статьи
[Documenting Your Project Using Sphinx](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html#documents)

Comment: А в markdown ее не поместить? :)

Comment: @gil9red Я этот файл редактировал *remarkable*. Но синтаксис  *reStructuredTex* и   *markdown* очень близки - легко можно подправить.

Comment: Просто, тут бы хотелось увидеть статью, но моего личного интереса заниматься этим нет :)

Comment: @gil9red   *тут бы хотелось увидеть статью* - мне тоже :-) Только вот я не нашёл места, куда её можно **тут** положить.

Comment: Положить в каком смысле? Ссылку оставить? Прикрепить файлом или картинкой? Или заверстать в reStructuredText  / md?

Comment: @gil9red Можно забрать по ссылке: https://hdd.tomsk.ru/file/dvikpxqe